# Printing an array/collection of javabeans in JSP

Tags: java, jsp

Is there a standard way of printing an array/collection elements of javabeans in JSP? All I know is the `<jsp:getProperty>` tag which can't do this. I know it can be done using custom tags, but it being such an essential requirement should be provided by JSP.

Also, I have read that using `setAttribute()` method of `PageContext`, `ServletContext` etc we can in a Servlet get the bean and work on it, but it's giving me `null` value.

```
pageContext.getAttribute("beanPropertyVariable")  //set in page scope
application.getAttribute("beanPropertyVariable")  //set in application scope
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: see if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102964/jstl-collection-iteration

Comment: I went through the above link but isnot there a simpler soln?

Answer (score 6):

The standard way is using [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) `<c:forEach>`.

Assuming that `${beans}` represents the collection of javabeans, here's an example:

```html
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
...
<c:forEach items="${beans}" var="bean">
    ${bean.property1}<br/>
    ${bean.property2}<br/>
    ${bean.property3}<br/>
</c:forEach>
```

That's also the simplest way you can get.

#### See also:

- [Our JSTL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)
- [Our Javabeans wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javabeans/info)

Answer (score 0):

you can use JSTL **c:foreach** tag like below

```
 <c:forEach items="${list}" var="var">
     ${var}<br/>
 </c:forEach>
```