# Import and print arraylist to JSP

Tags: java, jsp, arraylist

I have simple jsp page (page.jsp), and a simple java class (classWithArray) with an arraylist (list) in it.

How can I get access to the arraylist from jsp, for example to show it in a table?

Answer (score 1):

Use JSTL's `forEach` tag to iterate over a collection (an `ArrayList` in this case in particular) inside a JSP, take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102964/jstl-collection-iteration) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

you can iterate over an ArrayList using `c:forEach` tag from **JSTL**
Below is the sample code which iterates over an peopleList List.

```
<c:forEach var="person" items="${people.peopleList}">
        <tr>
          <td>${person.name}</td>
        </tr>
      </c:forEach>
```

use page tag to import a java.util.List in your JSP page use

```
<%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
```