# How to add values of all rows in a <table> and display as a 'Total' at the bottom row?

Tags: jsp

We have 10 rows displayed on the table on UI.

I want to add values of all Fees-1 and display as a 'Total' at the bottom row. How can I do it?

```
<table  id="tableID">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Fees-1</th>
        <th>Fees-2</th> 
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<c:forEach var="feesReport" items="${FEE_LIST}">
    <tr>
            <td>${feesReport.id}</td>
            <td>${feesReport.fees1}</td>
            <td>${feesReport.fees2}</td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>

// I want to add this new row at the bottom to show the Addition of fees


</tbody>
</table>
```

[UI - how it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GG4QF.jpg)

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I wanted. Thanks

Comment: Answer is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102964/calculate-total-sum-of-all-numbers-in-cforeach-loop